# setting column of dataframe by index of slice of same dataframe in pandas not working

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to set values of column for some rows of dataframe based on index of dataframe view. This does not work as expected. What are altrenatives?

i tried following code:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
dfb=df[df.a>1]
df['c']=np.nan
df.loc[dfb[dfb.a>2].index]['c']=10
df.loc[dfb[dfb.a>2].index]
```

expected that c column of df.loc[dfb[dfb.a>2].index] would be 10.   it is still nan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `df.loc[dfb[dfb.a>2].index]['c']=10` to `df.loc[dfb[dfb.a>2].index,'c']=10`.

Comment: because when you do df.loc[..]['c'] you're no longer saving the data on `df` but on a new dataframe derived from `df`. You first slice `df` into a new dataframe (let's call it `df_t`) and it is on `df_t` that you're assigning the value for column `c` to 10. You are chaining instructions instead of slicing properly